# Gestionar respuesta de una API de TPV Virtual

Tags: php, api

os pongo en contexto. Estoy integrando una API de TPV Virtual, en concreto esta https://api-developer.easypaymentgateway.com/hosted.html#section/Quick-Start, y básicamente lo que hago es construir el enlace del link de pago a través de una serie de campos (algunos obligatorios y otros no, definidos en https://api-developer.easypaymentgateway.com/encryption-fields.html). Hasta aquí todo correcto, consigo crear el enlace a la pantalla de pago, y realizar el pago, pero mi problema llega cuando intento gestionar la respuesta del TPV Virtual, ya que hay un parámetro llamado "statusURL", en el que yo tengo que indicar una supuesta dirección donde la API me mandará el resultado de la transacción en un formato XML como el siguiente:

```
      <Payfrex-response operation-size="1">
        <message>WorkFlow has finished successfully, for transaction Id: 101134</message>
        <operations>
          <operation sorted-order="1">
            <amount>10.00</amount>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <details>
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <netdirect version="4.1">
                  <approval>yes</approval>
                  <amount>10.00</amount>
                  <trans_id>21545</trans_id>
                  <error>none</error>
                  <fee>0.71</fee>
                  <time>{ts'2013-12-10 15:51:16'}</time>
                  <firstname>EURFirstname</firstname>
                  <lastname>EURLastname</lastname>
                  <email>netellertest_eur@neteller.com</email>
                  <custom_1>121</custom_1>
                  <custom_2>DEBIT</custom_2>
                  <total_fee>0.71</total_fee>
                  <client_currency>EUR</client_currency>
                  <client_amount>10.00</client_amount>
                  <merchant_currency>EUR</merchant_currency>
                  <merchant_amount>10.00</merchant_amount>
                  <fxrate>1.00000000</fxrate>
                </netdirect>
            </details>
            <merchantTransactionId>1223434</merchantTransactionId>
            <message>none</message>
            <operationType>DEBIT</operationType>
            <paymentDetails>
              <cardHolderName>Jtester</cardHolderName>
              <cardNumber>401200****1003</cardNumber>
              <cardNumberToken>7888967934961003</cardNumberToken>
              <cardType>VISA/CREDIT</cardType>
              <extraDetails />
              <issuerBank>EXTRAS TEST - VISA</issuerBank>
              <issuerCountry>US</issuerCountry>
            </paymentDetails>
            <optionalTransactionParams/>
            <EPGTransactionId>101134</EPGTransactionId>
            <paySolTransactionId>12544</paySolTransactionId>
            <paymentSolution>wirecard</paymentSolution>
            <status>SUCCESS</status>
          </operation>
        </operations>
        <optionalTransactionParams>
          <entry><key>merchantParam2</key><value></value></entry>
          <entry><key>merchantParam1</key><value></value></entry>
        </optionalTransactionParams>
        <status>SUCCESS</status>
        <workFlowResponse>
          <id>10</id>
          <name>Neteller</name>
          <version>8</version>
        </workFlowResponse>
      </Payfrex-response>
```

Lo que no sé es de qué forma recibir estos datos del XML ni qué tipo de dirección he de introducir en el statusURL para posteriormente recibir estos datos.

Os dejo aquí cómo construyo mi link de pago, también le paso como parámetro dos direcciones de dos archivos PHP, errorURL.php y successURL.php, donde debería yo de gestionar la respuesta, pero mi duda es como puedo desde estos dos archivos obtener los datos del XML anterior que os he mostrado. Toda ayuda es bienvenida, llevo unas semanas estancado en esta parte del proyecto y me vendría bien un poco de ayuda.

```
$data = "amount=" . $amount . "&apiVersion=" . $apiVersion . "&country=" . $country . "&currency=" . $currency .
    "&description=" . $description . "&merchantId=" . $merchantId . "&merchantTransactionId=" . $merchantTransactionId
    ."&operationType=" . $operationType . "&paymentSolution=" . $paymentSolution .
    "&addressLine1=" . $addressLine1 . "&addressLine2=" . $addressLine2 . "&city=" . $city . "&customerId=" . $customerId .
    "&firstname=" . $firstName . "&postCode=" . $postCode . "&customerCountry=" . $customerCountry .
    "&errorURL=" . $errorURL . "&successURL=" . $successURL . "&statusURL=" . $statusURL;

$method = 'aes-256-ecb';
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $merchantKey);
$integrityCheck = hash("sha256", $data);
$URI = "https://checkout-stg.easypaymentgateway.com/EPGCheckout/rest/online/tokenize";

$myParameters = "encrypted=" . urlencode(utf8_encode($encrypted)) . "&integrityCheck=" . $integrityCheck . "&merchantId=" . $merchantId;
$HtmlResult = "response";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URI);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$myParameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$HtmlResult = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: La doc de la API dice que en caso de éxito redigirá a `successURL.php`  y que allí tendrás la respuesta XML. Supongo que pusiste correctamente la dirección ¿no? Tú puedes agregar a curl esta opción: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` lo cual debería redireccionar a la URL de éxito o error. Para depurar puedes usar `curl_getinfo` por ejemplo: `$mURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`  Y luego haces un test de a donde está redirigiendo:  `var_dump($mURL);` y, si quieres testear la respuesta completa puedes hacer: `var_dump($HtmlResult);` Prueba y nos dices.

Comment: Claro, la redirección a la URL de éxito si que me funciona correctamente, pero mi pregunta es como puedo acceder a los datos del XML que supuestamente están en la dirección de statusURL, desde mi código de success.php, ya que mi propósito con todo esto es guardar los datos del XML en una base de datos que tengo, por ello necesito acceder a él, y en caso de éxito, guardar los datos de la transacción en la base de datos. Pero no se cómo tratar el atributo "statusURL" ya que no pone mucho al respecto.

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. La API te redigirá a una URL donde te ofrecerá un XML que podrás consumir / leer desde PHP usando alguna de las clases que de dispone PHP para ello ([DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) es más completa, te la recomiendo). ¿Cuál es tu problema, que no sabes cómo leer el XML que te responde la API o que en sí no sabes siquiera cómo ir a la URL a la que la API te redirige?